# Understanding attributes in application scope being an instance

Tags: java, jsp

I've two JSP files, where each one is accessed by different PCs.

In the first one, I'm creating an object of type `Integer`:

```
Integer var = 0;
application.setAttribute("name_var", var);
```

At the second one, I'm getting the attribute created before:

```
var = (Integer) application.getAttribute("name_var");
```

At this point everything is fine. I've my value at the second JSP, in a different PC.

Since Java is pass-by-value, where that values are references ([Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)), I guess I've the same instance in both the JSP files (being visited by different PCs).

So now, When I'm modifying my var value, and It doesn't appear modified in the other side, I don't understand why.

```
var++;
Output (in the JSP where the attribute was set): 0 (still)
```

Can anyone explain me what is happening? Have I to update the object with a `setAttribute` each time I modify its value?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var++` doesn't change the internal state of the Integer instance stored in the application. An Integer is immutable. Its state never changes.

The operation is equivalent to

```
int tmp = var.intValue();
tmp = tmp + 1;
var = Integer.valueOf(i);
```

So `var` now references another Integer instance than the one stored in the application.

The alternative is to store the new value in the application again, or to store a thread-safe, mutable value in the application:

```
AtomicInteger var = new AtomicInteger(0);
application.setAttribute("name_var", var);
...
var.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and for the AtomicInteger class. It'll be quite usefull =)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `var++`, you need to set the changed value back to the application attribute:

```
application.setAttribute("name_var", ++var);
```

The reason is autoboxing and immutability of `Integer` objects. When you say `var++`, java unboxes the `Integer` into a primitive `int` and increments that. But the result doesn't go into the attribute.

Comment: Something weird happened here.

Comment: no kidding - why does it show that I answered twice?

Comment: @gknicker StackOverflow probably stored the answer count as an Integer in the application, and thought incrementing it would change the application attribute :)